# Dealing with big size binary numbers in php

Tags: php, algorithm, memory

Algorithm:

Given a number n, list(L(n)) of all binary numbers of size n can be calculated from L(n-1) in the following way:

- Suppose array L(n-1) contains all the binary numbers of length n-1.
- Reverse L(n-1) and call RL(n-1).
- Append '0' to all binary numbers in L(n-1). Append '1' to all binary numbers in RL(n-1).
- Merge new appended arrays L(n-1) and RL(n-1) to get all the binary numbers of size n.
- Base Case,
  if n=1, output = [0,1].

Example, if n=2, We can get list of all binary numbers of size 2 in the following way:

- Let a = [0,1] be list of binary numbers of size (2-1) = 1.
- Let b = reverse of a = [1,0].
- Append 0 to all elements in a. New a = [00,11].
- Append 1 to all elements in b. New b = [11,10].
- Merge new a and b. [00,11,11,10].

Problem Statement: Given a number n, find list of n binary numbers.

Solution: A simple recursive or non-recursive solution works if n is less than 20.

Question: My code fails if a bigger number is passed lets say 40 and exceeds memory limits.
  Why?   - 'Coz For a number lets say 40, Total number of binary numbers will be power(2,40) which is huge(1048576 * 1048576). 
So, Is there any better algorithm or way to solve the above problem?

Comment: Why do you need a list of *all* numbers of a particular size?

Comment: Your result has a duplicate `11` and it's missing `01`.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the algorithm. Your goal of creating a list of all binary numbers of size N simply can't be done if there's not enough memory to hold all of them.

Comment: Right, it should be [00,01], the new a.

Comment: Okay, lets suppose I don't want all the numbers. But want only last n numbers. Then also the problem still holds.

Comment: I know it doesn't seem practical. What if I want only top 10 n sized binary numbers. I still need to calculate and find all the numbers and then take top 10. Or is there any trick or better way to handle this ?

Comment: The last number is `11111....` N times. The 2nd to last is that number with the last `1` changed to `0`. There's a pattern to how the low order digits change as you keep subtracting 1. Figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is store only first `n` numbers. It seems that in every case you only need first `n-1` numbers to only reverse and append with '1's for the correct output.